# Safe getElementById or try to determine if ID exists in GUI

Tags: google-apps-script

Method `UiInstance.getElementById(ID)` always returns `GenericWidget` object, even if ID does not exist.

Is there some way how to find out that returned object does not exist in my app, or check whether UI contains object with given ID?

---

Solution for UI created with GUI builder:

```
function getSafeElement(app, txtID) {
    var elem = app.getElementById(txtID);
    var bExists = elem != null && Object.keys(elem).length < 100;
    return bExists ? elem : null;
}
```

It returns null if ID does not exist. I didn't test all widgets for keys length boundary, so be careful and test it with your GUI.

EDIT: This solution works only within `doGet()` function. It does not work in server handlers, so in this case use it in combination with @corey-g answer.

Comment: Please unaccept my solution. Initial edition was not correct. For explanations please read Corey's answer. I edited my post basing on the Corey's solution only to avoid confusing. I can't delete my answer because it is already accepted by you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will only work in the same execution that you created the widget in, and not in a subsequent event handler where you retrieve the widget, because in that case everything is a GenericWidget whether or not it exists.

You can see for yourself that the solution fails:

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.createButton().setId("control").addClickHandler(
      app.createServerHandler("clicked")));
  app.add(app.createLabel(exists(app)));
  return app;
}

function clicked() {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.add(app.createLabel(exists(app)));
  return app;
}

function exists(app) {
  var control = app.getElementById("control");
  return control != null && Object.keys(control).length < 100;
}
```

The app will first print 'true', but on the click handler it will print 'false' for the same widget.

This is by design; a GenericWidget is a "pointer" of sorts to a widget in the browser. We don't keep track of what widgets you have created, to reduce data transfer and latency between the browser and your script (otherwise we'd have to send up a long list of what widgets exist on every event handler). You are supposed to keep track of what you've created and only "ask" for widgets that you already know exist (and that you already know the "real" type of).

If you really want to keep track of what widgets exist, you have two main options. The first is to log entries into ScriptDb as you create widgets, and then look them up afterwards. Something like this:

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  // You'd need to clear out old entries here... ignoring that for now
  app.add(app.createButton().setId('foo')
      .addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("clicked")));
  db.save({id: 'foo', type: 'button'});
  app.add(app.createButton().setId('bar'));
  db.save({id: 'bar', type: 'button'});
  return app
}
```

Then in a handler you can look up what's there:

```
function clicked() {
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var widgets = db.query({}); // all widgets
  var button = db.query({type: 'button'}); // all buttons
  var foo = db.query({id: 'foo'}); // widget with id foo
}
```

Alternatively, you can do this purely in UiApp by making use of tags

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var root = app.createFlowPanel();  // need a root panel
  // tag just needs to exist; value is irrelevant.
  var button1 = app.createButton().setId('button1').setTag(""); 
  var button2 = app.createButton().setId('button2').setTag("");
  // Add root as a callback element to any server handler
  // that needs to know if widgets exist
  button1.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("clicked")
      .addCallbackElement(root));
  root.add(button1).add(button2);
  app.add(root);
  return app;
}

function clicked(e) {
  throw "\n" +
      "button1 " + (e.parameter["button1_tag"] === "") + "\n" + 
      "button2 " + (e.parameter["button2_tag"] === "") + "\n" + 
      "button3 " + (e.parameter["button3_tag"] === "");
}
```

This will throw:

```
button1 true
button2 true
button3 false
```

because buttons 1 and 2 exist but 3 doesn't. You can get fancier by storing the type in the tag, but this suffices to check for widget existence. It works because all children of the root get added as callback elements, and the tags for all callback elements are sent up with the handler. Note that this is as expensive as it sounds and for an app with a huge amount of widgets could potentially impact performance, although it's probably ok in many cases especially if you only add the root as a callback element to handlers that actually need to verify the existence of arbitrary widgets.

Comment: The solution which the author pointed in the question works in a subsequent event, because a call of `Object.keys(control)` for a GenericWidget class object returns an array of 160 elements and other classes classes contain much less elements in the same array. The check to null is only a small check to make code faster if GAS team will change the code to return null for not exist IDs (but according your explanations it is unreal). The solution will stop to work if the `Object.keys` will return a list having more than 0 elements and less than 50 or something like that.

Comment: No, it does not work. I've edited my example to show how the original solution fails. You can try it yourself and see.

Comment: Understood. The length of the array is always 160 even for exist control. My answer is not correct and I am deleting it.

Comment: Ah, it's always nice to have a great user community like this. Until I saw your answer (and saw the issue with it) I never really thought about finding a way to do this, so kudos to you for that.

Comment: I can't delete my answer because it is already accepted. I edited my post using your solution with `setTag` method. I like it more rather than the ScriptDB solution.

Comment: OK, I realized that this is not as simple question as I thought. My problem was that I created UI using GUI builder and wanted to change some existing widgets acording to data in spreadsheet. So the first answer that I added to my answer was good solution in this case (no server handlers). Anyway thanks for your answer. If I combine it with the first, it will be perfekt.

Answer (score 3):

My initial solution is wrong, because it returns false exist controls.

A solution, based on Corey's answer, is to add the setTag("") method and here is ready to use code. It is suitable for event handlers only, because uses tags.

```js
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var btn01 = app.createButton("control01").setId("control01").setTag("");
  var btn02 = app.createButton("control02").setId("control02").setTag("");
  var handler = app.createServerHandler("clicked");
  handler.addCallbackElement(btn01);
  handler.addCallbackElement(btn02);
  btn01.addClickHandler(handler);
  btn02.addClickHandler(handler);
  app.add(btn01);
  app.add(btn02);
  return app;
}

function clicked(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.add(app.createLabel("control01 - " + controlExists(e, "control01")));
  app.add(app.createLabel("control02 - " + controlExists(e, "control02")));
  app.add(app.createLabel("fake - " + controlExists(e, "fake")));
  return app;
}

function controlExists(e, controlName) {
  return e.parameter[controlName + "_tag"] != null;
}
```

Comment: It's interesting solution. I tested it and it seams to work. A non-existing control has 160 methods, Label have 30, ListBox have 45 and TextBox have 47 methods.

Comment: @Chemik. It is better to create a function and use it everywhere. If the GAS team will create a control having more than 100 methods, then changing 100 to bigger value in one place solves this issue in whole code, till the next time.

Comment: Yes I created function `getSafeElement(app, txtID)` that returns object or null.

Comment: @Megabyte1024 : didn't you forget the callbackElement in your new code ?  PS: Your exchange with Corey was very instructive ! I definitely like this forum ;-)

Comment: @Sergeinsas. Definitely a call of the callbackElement method is required if to use input controls which pass theirs values as a callback function parameters. This example does not have such controls and it is not required. I tested this code before posting and it works correctly.

Comment: You're right indeed... now it's clear as cristal ! thanks :-)

Comment: If you want to test this without concern for the number of methods, just check whether control.toString() === 'GenericWidget'

Comment: I tested it - `app.getElementById("noID").toString()` returns string "Generic" not "GenericWidget"

Comment: Yes, sorry, "Generic" and not "GenericWidget".

Comment: @Megabyte1024, you do need the callback element, as in my original code. Your code will only work for the widget that fired the event, which happens to be the one widget you are checking. All other widgets will be "false" even if they exist. My code is correct for all widgets.

Comment: @CoreyG. You wrote, that my code works only for widget that fired the event. Could you please to explain me in details. I think I miss something. As far as I understood the firing widget in my code is the button but the exist function returns `true` for the exist `control` and returns `false` for not existent `control1`.

Comment: If you had another control that exists in the app, say label1, that wasn't the control that was clicked to fire the event, it would also be false. Look at my original example where there are two buttons, one of which is clicked, but both correctly show "true". If I didn't have the callbackElement with that root panel, button2 would show false even thought it does exist.